# Como implemetar MouseListeners numa GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing

Eu criei uma GUI para um Board de um jogo com uma GridLayout de 8x8. Nessa Grid preciso ter um mouse listener em cada um dos containers. Como é que consigo isso?
Já tentei de diversas formas e não estou a conseguir.

### Code:

```java
    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        GridLayout gl_Board = new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5);
        board = new Board();
        JPanel Board = new JPanel(gl_Board);
        Board.add(board);
        board.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8, 2, 2));
        Board.setBounds(10, 25, 708, 423);
        frame.getContentPane().add(Board);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ola

Crie um botão e adicione um listener nele

Por exemplo

```
JButton button = new JButton();
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("cliquei no botao");

            }
        });
```

Comment: Não se esqueça de adicionar o botao ao painel